# Portable Ubuntu External Drive ? Please Help

Tags: system-installation

I want to create an external Ubuntu HardDrive but I want to know that is there any way to install it without adding changes to the Boot option menu. I currently have Windows 7 installed on my PC but i don't want a choosing menu (Win7/Ubuntu) each time my PC starts, I want it to be like a plug and play device. Is it possible please reply in steps!

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer: If you install Ubuntu on a external USB you will not be prompted to choose your OS everytime you boot your PC.

The scenario you are thinking of is when Ubuntu and Windows are both installed on the same harddrive and the GRUB boot menu asks which partition to boot from.

This is different when booting form an external drive and is actually handled by the BIOS.

This is very system specific so I can't give detailed instruction but here are the steps you want to take. Lets pretend you already have your Ubuntu liveUSB made.

Power down your computer and connect the external harddrive.

Boot the computer into the BIOS Boot options menu (this is system specific and is usually done by pressing either the ESC or a F* key during bootup).

In this menu there should be an option to boot from USB Drive. Select that and you will boot from the external harddrive.

To achieve a plug and play like experience you can do some more messing around in the BIOS. If you go into the BIOS Menu you should have an option to change the boot order. Your internal harddrive should be first (CD might be first). Change this so USB is the first in the boot order.

Now anytime you boot the PC with the USB plugged in it will automatically boot from the external harddrive, if it finds a bootable device.

**Note:** Much of this deals with your BIOS and is system specific and not really Ubuntu related.

Comment: I tested installing ubuntu on a external 160Gib HardDrive I created 3 partitions sdb1-/boot, sdb2-/,sdb3-Swap & Installed Grub on sdb1, restarted and the Ubuntu(Humanity) froze, Restarted again and Win7 fixed its Startup, and the third restart with the extDrive as 1st boot device-- Error Occurred (no boot 00 bla bla bla)and Installation was unsuccessful , so what to do in order to make a ubuntu plug'n'play ExtHDD without making any changes to Win 7 and seriously I DO NOT WANT TO HAVE A DUAL BOOT AT ALL, please help me in this Boot Case Scenario

Comment: And all the bios related stuff is Cool I have all control over the place need no help in that, just want to make use of my ExtHdd as Ubuntu Portable PluG'n'Play

Comment: Going to try once again - let's hope it works

Comment: Failed once again- it started once and hanged up in the middle and after the force restart i got this message ---- Boot0:GPT Boot0:error

Comment: Job Done - finally with the help of - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDM2LqFoHv4

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were asking. Glad you got it figured out though.

Answer (score 0):

There might a setting in the BIOS to allow booting from external drives - press F2 or whatever it is on your computer to enter the setup.

If you want to boot to multiple Operating Systems, you may need something like Grub or Grub2 installed to allow a the selection of which System to boot.

I am not experienced in this area - try searching for 'dual booting' on Wikipedia or Google, or on the forum.

Comment: Sorry - half a minute to late. Good answer @dan08.

Comment: I tested installing ubuntu on a external 160Gib HardDrive I created 3 partitions sdb1-/boot, sdb2-/,sdb3-Swap & Installed Grub on sdb1, restarted and the Ubuntu(Humanity) froze, Restarted again and Win7 fixed its Startup, and the third restart with the extDrive as 1st boot device-- Error Occurred (no boot 00 bla bla bla)and Installation was unsuccessful , so what to do in order to make a ubuntu plug'n'play ExtHDD without making any changes to Win 7 and seriously I DO NOT WANT TO HAVE A DUAL BOOT AT ALL, please help me in this Boot Case Scenario